# CodeIgniter: trying to call constructor method to check if user is logged in (causes endless redirection loop)

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, constructor

I've got a Problem with CodeIgniter 2.1.2 and stuck for hours try to solve it :-/

I know there are plenty(!) of threads about that, but i couldn't find a solution for my problem.

I want to load a method in my constructor to check if a user is logged in, so i tried this:

```
class my_class extends CI_Controller
{
public function __construct();
parent::__construct();

$this->check(); //doesn't work, endless redirection loop
}
```

"check()" is:

```
public function check()
{
    if (! $this->session->userdata('logged_in'))  
    {     
        redirect('/login'); // tried with & without '/'
    }
}
```

method "login()" looks like this:

```
public function login()
{
  ...
  //do form validation stuff and on success:
  if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
    {
     $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', TRUE);
     redirect('/entry'); 
    }
   //load login_view
}
```

method "entry()":

```
public function entry()
{
  //$this->check();//Old (redundant) Version

  //Authorized and Happy...
}
```

// some other methods, also call the check() method first

So my question is, why the calls in the methods works (but with much redundant calls)
and the call in the constructor give me an endless loop? Do I miss something?? 
(I also didn't change stuff in the htaccess files..)

Thx in advance :-)

Comment: What if someone isn't logged in, and they are redirected to the login page?  Will it still check if they are logged in even on the login pages?

Comment: if i use the "working" version, a user who isn't logged in, gets redirected to the login page till he logs in correctly.

Comment: If method login is within the same class then it will call the constructor again and redirect again.

Comment: You would be better off doing the authentication bit in a `MY_Controller`constructor, then extend your other controllers with `MY_Controller`.

Comment: I am saying what @karmafunk is saying.  If they are on the login page, will it still call the `__construct()` and redirect?  That is where you are getting your infinite redirect.

Comment: Within your constructor you could only check the login state if the user is not on page login.

Comment: Sorry Guys, i dont get it :-/ I extend the CI_Controller with a "My_Controller" and load that one instead of the CI one in my "my_class". But I dont understand which parts i need to put in the "My"-Version and which should stay in the "my_class"...

Comment: posted solution did not have anything to do with my_controller, or extending the class -- because you did not mention either of those in yr post.  the key thing i was suggesting is to have the redirect happen clearly in the constructor. ANYWAY - is there something bad happening after the redirect after the form validation...?

Comment: cryode has a great point, i edited my answer to make it more clear. (but the sloppy braces are still there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on what commenters have said:

Ignoring the `MY_Controller` solution entirely for a moment, the issue is that your `__construct()` method -- and subsequently, `$this->check()` -- is being called on every controller, including your login controller.

1. Load homepage. Constructor loads `check()`.
2. Not logged in. Redirect to `/login`.
3. Login constructor loads `check()`.
4. Not logged in. Redirect to `/login`.

... and so on and so forth.

The solution is to **check what URL is being accessed**, and if it belongs to your login controller/method, then don't perform the redirect.

```
public function check()
{
    if ($this->uri->uri_string() !== 'login' && ! $this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {     
        redirect('login');
    }
}
```

Inversely, your login method should check if the user is indeed already logged in, and if so, redirect him to your homepage or something. But I digress.

---

The `MY_Controller` solution involves [creating a base controller](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY) whose constructor performs the logged in check. Then, any controllers where you want to perform that check should extend `MY_Controller` instead of `CI_Controller`.

Note that your login controller will **not** extend `MY_Controller`, because you don't want to perform the check, or your infinite loop will show up again.

Comment: Seems legit ;-) Do I necessarily need to extend the CI Controller? I now build a working version with a login controller and a controller which only logged in user can use(redirected from login controller, if check was valid), both extend only the Ci controller. I dont see the advantage of extending my own controller (what doesnt mean, that there isnt one) ;-) I think i should read the article from phil AGAIN :-)

Comment: If you're only doing a login check in a couple place, no, you don't *need* to create a base controller (all your standard controllers should extend `CI_Controller` already, that's normal). However, if you want to add new controllers w/ a login check in the future, it will save you extra work, especially if you ever wanted to change how the login check is performed (like renaming the method or something).

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to be precise, but here goes.

I assume that login() is *not* a method in the my_class class/controller. If they are, this could be the cause of the error as the constructor would be called each time.

A better method would be to have a secure controller extend CI_Controller, e.g. Auth_Controller. This would be in application/libraries/MY_Controller.php file.

Your secure controllers would extend Auth_Controller, and the check() would be made in its contructor. The login controller would not extend Auth_Controller.

Comment: So you say, I need 3 Controllers? One which extends the CI (My_Controller), One which is the Login_Controller (extends CI_Controller) and another one which extends "My_Controller"??

Answer (score 0):

here are some quick suggestions, but first make sure
you autoload session library in config/autoload.php

this is not the login class. you would not have a redirect in the login class, 
you would just go straight to $this->enterLogin() or whatever the method name is, so that it does not loop.

```
 // Capitalize the first letter of the class!!
 class My_class extends CI_Controller
 {
     public function __construct();
     parent::__construct();

     // check if login is false
     // redirect here in the constructor, not buried in a method
     // note the underscore in the name _checkLogin() to make that method private

     if ( $this->_checkLogin() == false ) 
    { redirect( '/login/', 'refresh' );  }

 } // end constructor


 // private function 
 function _checkLogin(){
    if (! $this->session->userdata('logged_in'))  
    {   return false ;  }
    else
    { return true; } 

  } //
```

Comment: If the login method is in this class or a class, which extends your "My_class", i've got the same endless loop :-(

Comment: This is the weirdest brace style I have ever seen.