# what is the best practice for role based login system in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, authentication, controller

I am working on one role based login system. Actually, What should I do to the controller, model and the views in this role based login system to allocate different access criteria.

I am little confused about how to set and access for the user according to the role.

Mainly I am not sure about how to allocate different view as a role.

ex. I apply if condition to check role and then view according to the role the menu show the different links. like main admin can only watch account tab. the user can not see the account tab.

I also set the same if condition with the session in the controller for preventing direct access to that page.

Here is my code which I applied to menu and controller.

```
<?php 
        $login_role= $this->session->userdata('user_data');
        if($login_role['user_role'] === 'super_admin'){

            ?><li><a href="<?php echo base_url('account/view_account'); ?>">
            <div>Account</div></a></li><?php
        }
    ?>
```

and the same condition in the controller

```
 public function index() 
{
    $login_role= $this->session->userdata('user_data');

    if($login_role['user_role'] === 'super_admin')
    {
        $this->load->model('location_model');
        $city_list = $this->location_model->get_city_list();
        $state_list = $this->location_model->get_state_list();
        //log_message('info', 'City and State list will sucessfully loded.');         
        $this->load->view('admin/account_insert',['city_list'=>$city_list,'state_list'=>$state_list]);    
    } else {

        redirect('admin/dashboard','refresh');
    }


}
```

I am not sure about is this safe to use like this way. or I have to do something else as a good practice.

Comment: You might also check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15423441/3585500) that puts the `logged_in()` check in the controller's constructor if you want to make an entire controller restricted. It's for CI 2, but the gist is the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am using a single Controller Login system for all user roles. I have a table of user roles and I have role id in users table. Then I have controller names matching those roles. When user login, I check for role and redirect the user to that controller after verification. Following is the index function of my Login Controller.

```
public function index()
{
    if(!$this->isLoggedIn())
    {
        $data['title']='Title You want to set on Page';
        if($_POST)
        {
            $config=array(
                array(
                    'field' => 'email',
                    'label' => 'Email',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email',
                ),
                array(
                    'field' => 'password',
                    'label' => 'Password',
                    'rules' => 'trim|required',
                ),
            );
            $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
            if($this->form_validation->run()==false)
            {
                $data['errors']=validation_errors();
                $this->load->view('static/head', $data);
                $this->load->view('admin/login');
            }
            else
            {
                $user=$this->admin_model->checkUser($_POST);
                if(!empty($user))
                {
                    if($user['role']==1)
                    {
                        $user['type']='admin';
                    }
                    elseif($user['role']==2)
                    {
                        $user['type']='team';
                    }
                    elseif($user['role']==3)
                    {
                        $user['type']='client';
                    }
                    elseif($user['role']==4)
                    {
                        $user['type']='manager';
                    }
                    $this->session->set_userdata($user);
                    redirect(base_url().$user['type']);
                }
                else
                {
                    $data['errors']='The credentials you have provided are incorrect or your account has not been approved yet.';
                    $this->load->view('static/head', $data);
                    $this->load->view('admin/login');
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('static/head', $data);
            $this->load->view('admin/login');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        redirect(base_url().$this->session->userdata['type']);
    }

}
```

Its working perfectly for me. Furthermore in each Controller I have functions to check if the user is logged in for this role like this

```
public function isLoggedIn()
{
    if(!empty($this->session->userdata['id'])&& $this->session->userdata['type']=='team')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And I render my index function of that controller. E.g Following is the team controller index function

```
public function index()
{
    if($this->isLoggedIn())
    {
        $data['menu']=$this->team_model->getMenuItems();
        $data['task_logs']=$this->admin_model->getAllLogs();

        $data['title']='Title';
        $this->load->view('static/head',$data);
        $this->load->view('static/header');
        $this->load->view('static/sidebar');
        $this->load->view('team/dashboard');
        $this->load->view('static/footer');
    }
    else
    {
        redirect(base_url());
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice solution dear.  :-)